# get_category only returning details for 'uncategorized'

Tags: php, categories, slug, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using the ACF Taxonomy field add-on to select a category and (hopefully) return details for that category, e.g. slug, title etc.
The custom field `get_field('category_test')` returns the category ID, in this case being `4`, I then want to use this category ID to fetch the category slug in one instance, and the category title in another.
I'm trying this in my functions.php:

```
function get_cat_slug($cat_id) {
$cat_id = (int)$cat_id;
$category = &get_category($cat_id);
return $category->slug;
}
```

and calling it in my page.php using `echo get_cat_slug(get_field('category_test'));` but the slug that is being returned is `uncategorized` instead of the category 'test' with the ID of 4. Even trying this `$catinfo = get_category(get_field('category_test'));` returns the array for `uncategorized`, everything I try doesn't seem to work, is there any reason for this? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly this is because the ID you are passing to get_category is wrong (false or 0).
i don't know how you configured the taxonomy add on but do a vaR_dump and double check what data the get_field function is returning, maybe it's an array with a single value in it :

```
get_category(array_pop(get_field('category_test')));
```